# 12 VDC to 6 VDC to power a radio

Tags: power-supply, power, resistors, radio

I have a Grundig radio that requires 6 V and 500 mA negative center pin.  It is very sensitive to noisy wall warts, so I want to power it from my very noise-free ham radio 12 V power supply.

Can I use the "resistor" method for this purpose?  If I use two 10 W, 10 kΩ resistors, would that be adequate?

Comment: No, you can't use a resistor. Get a non-noisy wall wart.

Comment: to get 500 mA through 10,000 ohms will require 5,000 volts, not 12.

Comment: Show me a "non-noisy" wall wart.  I tried several - not cheap ones, either.  This Grundig is notorious for not behaving well with wall warts.

Comment: The resistors are used in the Voltage divider circuit, not individually.

Comment: You said "negative polarity" - do you mean that the radio requires -6V?  It will be a problem getting that from a +12V supply.

Comment: Your two 10K resistors across 12 volts will draw 0.6 mA. If your radio attempts to draw 0.6 mA, the mid-point of your voltage divider will drop to 0.0 V. The resistors will dissipate 7.2 mW - save some money and use 1/8W resistors rather than 10 W.

Comment: @Gfmucci Any *old* wall wart, with a linear supply in it, will probably be pretty quiet. If your radio is truly that sensitive that even a switching supply with good filtering won't work, a linear supply is the way to go. Just know it'll waste a bunch of energy and get pretty hot.

Comment: Will something like this:  https://www.ebay.com/itm/254837704074?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20200818143230%26meid%3D8539db2aed964da4bb9c6de9e1cfdaad%26pid%3D101224%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D5%26sd%3D185167306164%26itm%3D254837704074%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DDefaultOrganicWeb&_trksid=p2047675.c101224.m-1   be noise-free?  Amazon doesn't sell linears.  Need to go to ebay.

Comment: With just consuming 500mA, I doubt much energy will be wasted.  As many say, various methods of achieving purpose has tradeoffs.  I'm willing to trade off a nickels worth of lost energy for a quiet, noise-free radio.

Comment: @Peter Bennett  Sorry, Peter.  I meant "negative center pin".  What I decided to do, (and it will be seen by many as a wonky, inefficient, inelligant solution) is this:  Bought a cheap 6 volt AGM battery.  Bought a cheap trickle charger.  I already have a plug in count down timer.  Plug the radio into the battery. No interference.  None.  Charge the battery every few days via the countdown timer and trickle charger.

Comment: I realize these 1 amp "battery maintainer/trickle chargers" are NOISY.  That's why it will be charging the battery when I'm not using the radio.

Answer (score 3):

Voltage across a resistor depends on current through it (V=RI) so a resistor voltage divider is a very poor voltage regulator.

Why not use an actual 6V voltage regulator like [7806](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/41/4f/b3/b0/12/d4/47/88/CD00000444.pdf/files/CD00000444.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000444.pdf)? Just add any electrolytic (1-100µF) at the input and output, and a small heat sink.

Link to [example schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93103/what-do-the-capacitors-on-in-and-out-of-an-lm7805-voltage-regulator). Capacitor values are not critical.

It will dissipate 6V dropout x 500mA = 3W so you need a small heat sink like 10°C/W ([example](https://www.reichelt.com/fr/en/heat-sinks-finger-c7767.html?ACTION=2&GROUPID=7767&START=0&OFFSET=16&CCOUNTRY=443&LANGUAGE=en&CCOUNTRY=443&LANGUAGE=fr&LANGUAGE=EN&r=1&SID=93de6fd4ff46e164406e4f9c99cd5eeb25c427bf5227b29ea01d7)). If you put it in an aluminium box you can use that as a heat sink, with a drop of thermal paste. The metal tab is connected to ground, which makes it easier.

Comment: Is there a wiring diagram using the 7806?  What other components are required?

Comment: Would it need to be shielded/grounded to eliminate noise/hum?

Comment: No need to shield it. Was your radio noisy with wall warts using switching power supplies?

Comment: All wall warts on Amazon seem to be switching power supplies.  Yes, different warts produced different types of noise.  Some a 60 Hz hum, others a higher pitched whine.

Comment: Yeah, only way to find an oldskool transformer wall wart these days seems to be to dig in the old stuff in the attic